# Allow Excel to execute actions while application.Speech.Speak is active

Tags: vba, excel, doevents

I have a code that acts as a countdown timer(up to three timers on one sheet), and several actions occur while the timer is active. Everything is working fine right now. When any of the timers hit 0 the following snippet of code is run:

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C8").Interior.Color = 255 Or Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G8").Interior.Color = 255 Or Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K8").Interior.Color = 255 Then

Beep
Application.Speech.Speak ("Part is done")
Beep

Call AlertTIMER
Else
Exit Sub
End If
```

The `AlertTIMER` sub that is called from the snippet above runs `Application.Wait`, creating a 3 second pause between when it was last called and when it can be called next. The reason I have included the wait function is because while `Application.Speech` is running I'm unable to complete any other actions (such as clicking the "Stop" command button which terminates the Alert sub).

Is there a way to allow command buttons to be pressed while Application.Speech is active so I can remove the Application.Wait function? Or do I need to keep my workaround of Application.Wait?

I have tried using `DoEvents` by placing it before the first beep but it did not work.

Comment: Also, if you would like me to supply other portions of the code or further explain, I can... Just there's a lot going on so I tried to be concise.

Comment: I'm not really clear with what you're trying to do. If you're just trying to break the `application.speech.speak` while executing, You can ctrl+break.

Comment: Okay, so the Alert sub (Beep "Part is done" Beep) is going off, and then there is a 3 second pause (due to `Application.Wait`). This pause allows for someone to click a commandbutton (Stop) which will cause the Alert Sub to stop being triggered. If they don't, then after the 3 seconds have expired, the Alert sub is called again. If I do not include the pause (which Ideally I would like to remove) , then it is impossible to click the commandbutton (stop) while the Alert sub is active. I'm looking for a way to be able to execute actions while the sub Alert is active (Beep "Part is done" Beep).

Comment: I do not want to have to use ctrl+break as sometimes I will be executing an action but want to the Alert sub to continue. One example of this is there are multiple timers. So if two are triggering the alert, I want to be able to click stop on the one, and then complete an action... while the alert sub continues on since the second stop was no clicked. ctrl+break would jump me out of both. Also, I would like to avoid ctrl+break as i dont want to have to click something on the keyboard and I dont believe sendkeys is considered reliable - so I dont want to include it as part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Application.Speech.Speak "Part is done", SpeakAsync:=True
```

Source: https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/make-excel-talk-with-application-speech-speak-vba/

Answer (score 0):

you can add the instruction DoEvents it will allow the OS to check any other interaction like clicks... check for some tutorials about this

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please expand your answer to include more details. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more information.

Comment: He already said that he tried DoEvents and it didn't yield.  I'm having the same problem.  I've even tried putting multiple DoEvents in a row and it still doesn't yield

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.Speech.Speak ("Part is done",true)
```

that should enable you to maintain the functionality with the workbook